# How do I test a mobile app update using Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-ios, python-appium

Is it possible to automate the updating of an app using Appium? 
My scenario is that I need to install an older version of the app and in my test I have to install the newest version. 
But the desired capabilities for `appium:app` is defined as the latest app. I was thinking that I can override this desired capability to be an older version first? But, for now, I am still not sure how to execute this.
How should I go about testing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using "app" capability install the old version.
Then, use driver.installApp() to install the newer version. This will upgrade the app by default.

Note that you might have to cast the driver to use the installApp() command.

For e.g. if you are initialising the driver like below,
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver():

Then, you may have to cast the driver like below:
((AndroidDriver) driver).installApp();

Similarly for iOS,
((IOSDriver) driver).installApp();

The Appium's project lead has created a very good article on this topic for Android. You can read about it here: https://appiumpro.com/editions/9-testing-android-app-upgrades